# Asssembly with EF context class connection string in an assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Hope you can help with this one, although so for here does seem to b a resolution.

I have a class library which connects to a SQL Server database using an EF context class with a connection string in the app.config file.

I then reference this dll in an ASP.NET app but have to add the connection sting again in the web.config file

I would have though by referencing the dll and thus the connection string, I would not require to add the connection string again.

Perhaps I am missing something or has anyone else found a resolution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

The connection string is read from the executables app.config (i.e. windows forms/WPF/console applications). For web applications the connection string is taken from the web.config file of the startup project (i.e. where the global.aspx.cs) is located.

You cannot use the app.config from your model DLL directly. You have to put the connection strings in the "main" projects.

What might help is some kind of scripting, but that's up to you.

Comment: Thanks for getting back so quickly, I had a feeling it was something along those lines. One of my colleagues suggested creating it as a service but that is not the route I would choose to go down but I like your suggestion. I could create a Nuget Package with a text file tht would update the web.config. Definite food for thought

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the configSource attribute and configure and external file:

```
<ConnectionString configSource="shared.config" />
```

The content of the file replaces the content of the element though. Another thing is that you need to include the file in your web app project and toggle copy to output.

And another warning:

> the external connection strings file must be in the same directory as
>   the root web.config file, so you'll have to take precautions to ensure
>   you don't check it into your source repository.

More about that and best practices about deploying sensitive data can be found here:

http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/best-practices-for-deploying-passwords-and-other-sensitive-data-to-aspnet-and-azure#con

Comment: Hi Santhos, thanks for getting back to me. I can see there are a number of possibilities to do this but each has a caveat. Maybe MS will look into this for cross platform development when Web can not easily be incorporated with the other MS platforms